# Application.Run and range parameter?

Tags: excel, vba

If I have an excel function such as:

```
=my_function(A1:C4)
```

and I want to call this from VBA like:

```
Dim t as variant
t = Application.Run("my_function",X)
```

What is the simplest way for X to represent A1:C4?

Comment: Have you tried: `Application.Run("'my_function ""A1:C4""'")`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your range has to come from a worksheet, so if you define that range first and then pass it to the function in your other workbook (I assume that's what you want to do since you wouldn't use Application.Run otherwise).  So the following code will do the trick:

```
Sub RunFunctionInAnotherWorkbook()
    Dim rThisRange as Range
    Dim vResult as Variant

    Set rThisRange = ActiveSheet.Range("A1:C4")

    vResult = Application.Run("'MyOtherWorkbook.xls'!TheModuleName.TheSubName", rThisRange)
End Sub
```

And the function in the workbook "MyOtherWorkbook.xls":

```
Function TheSubName(inputRange as Range) as Variant

    'Work your magic here

End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't try it, but wouldn't

```
t=myfunction(range)
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest syntax is

```
Application.Run("my_function", [A1:c4])
```